# Zend Framework-Socal Nick Zend google login's not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, google-signin

Google's *login* is not working.

Can you please tell me what's issue?

How can i trace error?

This is my **composer** file:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "neilime/zf2-twb-bundle": "2.*@stable",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.0",
        "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "1.0.0",
        "zf-commons/zfc-base": "0.1.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "1.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools":"dev-master",
        "zf-commons/zfc-rbac": "2.4.x",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize":"1.4.*",
        "dudapiotr/zftable": "dev-master",
        "imagine/imagine": "dev-master",
        "easypost/easypost-php": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.1.*@dev",
        "Zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.*",
        "payum/payum":"0.13.*",
        "payum/payum-module": "0.13.*@dev",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "2.2.*",
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "1.14.1",
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth-doctrine-orm": "1.*",
        "goalio/goalio-forgotpassword": "1.*",
        "goalio/goalio-forgotpassword-doctrine-orm": "1.*",
        "zfr/zfr-pusher-module": "1.*",
        "brianlmoon/gearmanmanager": "dev-zf-gearman-manager-fork",
        "tfountain/zf-gearman-manager": "dev-master",
        "mapado/mysql-doctrine-functions": "1.*",
        "tburschka/zf2-doctrine-sql-logger": "dev-master",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "dev-master"
    }
```

It's redirected after validate google accounts to again login page, but facebook login is working fine!.

**site url**:

http://ec2-52-8-68-187.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/login

Comment: Hello, please reply if any solutions for this.